# Using Emoticons in Android

Tags: android

I am setting text on a TextView. Text is getting fetched from an EditText. I am able to see all the text that i type in EditText***(Including Emotions/Emojis)***

Then can someone please explain why do we have Emoticons Library in Android ? *I did not include any library in my gradle file. Still it works fine. I see all emojis typed in EditText finally in my TextView*

Answer (score 1):

The EmojiCompat support library aims to keep Android devices up to date with the latest emoji. It prevents your app from showing missing emoji characters in the form of ☐, which indicates that your device does not have a font to display the text. By using the EmojiCompat support library, your app users do not need to wait for Android OS updates to get the latest emoji.

For more information, you can check this site.
[Click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html)

Answer (score 0):

> The EmojiCompat support library aims to keep Android devices up to date with the latest emoji. It prevents your app from showing missing emoji characters in the form of ☐, which indicates that your device does not have a font to display the text. By using the EmojiCompat support library, your app users do not need to wait for Android OS updates to get the latest emoji.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html

So basically if your device supports all new Emojis, you should have no problem rendering those - even without the library.

Comment: ok, so you mean to say that because my phone has an updated OS, i did not have to include a library for emoticons in my project?

Comment: If your target audience may see Emojis which aren't supported by their respective OS (e.g. messaging apps), you should include the library.